# Mongodb indexes is not removed after deleting particular field

Tags: mongodb

There is a collection **"companies"** in my mongo database. I removed **"website"** field that was a unique field from schema of that collection and continue to test my application but its gives error.When i see indexes of that collection , its show deleted field indexes also. So why this problem is occuring and what is the solution?

```
> db.companies.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "dokkit.companies"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1
        },
        "name" : "name_1",
        "ns" : "dokkit.companies",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "website" : 1
        },
        "name" : "website_1",
        "ns" : "dokkit.companies",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the index on that field 
[db.collection.dropIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)